# Икра и... икра

Tags: омонимы

Икра рыбы и икра на ноге — омонимы. Но случайное ли это сходство слов? Хотя, на сколько я знаю, мышца на ноге правильно произносится с ударением на И.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы будете смеяться, но слова действительно родственны. Не в русском, разумеется, а в индоевропейском вообще (и латинском - в часности).

(рыбы). Общеслав. Родственно лат. iecor, латышск. aknas, «печень», авест. yākarə тж., ирл. iuchair «икра» и т. д. Объясняется как суф. производное (суф. -r-) от той же основы, что и лат. jacio «метать, разбрасывать, рассеивать». Икра буквально — «выбрасываемое из внутренностей», затем — «внутренности, какой-л., орган животного» (в частности, печень, ср. также польск. диал. ikra «вымя», икра (2)}}

(ноги). Общеслав., имеющее соответствия в балт. яз. В соврем. значении возникло на базе икра «внутренности». См. икра (1)}} (рыбы). Ср. нидерланд.

(Кажется, это словарь Шанского, в базе на http://www.onlineslovari.com/ идет как "безымянный")